# Thread safety of compiler-generated copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm doing something as seemingly innocuous as

`Foo* p = getAFoo(); /*not really doing this but good enough here*/`

`Foo f(*p);`

And I'm relying on the compiler-generated copy constructor. `Foo` contains quite a few member variables.

It's possible that a method call from another thread modifies the state of `*p` during the copy. I think that could leave `f` in a corrupted state.

Do I need to write the copy constructor myself and use a instance-level mutex? That would be a headache as I could easily miss a member variable when taking the copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, compiler generated copy constructor is not safe, and yes you have to use a mutex. More interesing question is where to put that mutex lock. You may try to put in copy constructor body, but that method could be ineffective and error prone. Let's say you have this code:

```
Foo::Foo( const Foo &an )
{
    scope_lock( mutex );
}
```

First of all, you will not be able to use copy constructors for members, as that will happen before lock, so you will have to use copy assignment, which easily can be less effective. But there is even a bigger problem - if Foo is inherited from a class with non-trivial data members. When you get to body of Foo's constructor parent class constructor is already done, so you have the same issue.

Better solution would be to use mutex around statement `Foo f(*p)` and where it is modified. That can be achieved by making Foo's copy ctor private/protected and create a method copy() which locks instance mutex and then creates a copy using copy ctor:

```
Foo Foo::copy() 
{
    scope_lock( mutex );
    return *this;
}
```

Even better solution would be to redesign your program that this condition would not happen at all.

Comment: The solution is C++11 constructor delegation. Delegate from the visible copy constructor to a private constructor that takes a reference to the lock guard: `Foo::Foo(const Foo& other, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>&& lock) : stuff(other.stuff) {} Foo::Foo(const Foo& other) : Foo(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(other.mutex), other) {}` This is unreadable as a comment, I should write an answer.

Comment: @Casey how is that simpler or easier to read than `Foo Foo::copy() { scope_lock( mutex ); return Foo( *this ); }`?

Comment: Constructor delegation is by no means cleaner than your approach. But it uses a cool new feature, so people will love it ;-)

Comment: @Slava The idiomatic way to copy an object in C++ is `Foo a = b;`, not `Foo a = b.copy();`. Not supporting the idiomatic syntax leads to all kinds of problems, e.g, How do I copy a container of `Foo`?

Comment: @Casey your constructor does not support idiomatic syntax either, so what is the point?

Comment: @Slava [Of course it does, that *is* the point](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31ee5920814a68cd "Live at Coliru").

Comment: @Slava I'm not sure why you'd want to inherit from a class with internal synchronization, [but ok](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f111810ef50af94 "Coliru again"). What point are you trying to make here?

Comment: @Casey for the same reason why I would want to inherit from any other class. What point? Implement that inheritance in code and I think my point will become obvious

Comment: @Casey that code is not ok, copy of derived class should be thread safe as well.

Answer (score 4):

A copy constructor is not thread-safe. So, yes, you must use a mutex here. But be aware, that also the thread that modifies the state must use the mutex. Only using the mutex in the copy constructor is not enough.